# shell script not sending mail accurately using SMTP server

Tags: linux, shell, smtp

I wrote script to send mail automatically using an SMTP connection but when I execute the script, sometimes it works and sometimes it is not sending mail. Behavior is quite ambiguous.

```
Environment : Linux Server Fedora 14 
Mailing Client : Lotus Notes 8.5.2
```

Please find script below.

```
# Function for sending email
sendemail(){
date=`date '+%d-%m-%Y'`
dbDir=/var/lib/MYSQLBACKUP/$date
dbname='DBNAME'
log_file="${dbDir}/${dbname}_${date}.log"
attached_file="${dbname}_${date}.log"
echo $log_file
echo $attached_file
encoded_log_file=`cat $log_file | openssl base64`
#echo $encoded_log_file
( echo open 172.40.201.31 25
sleep 8
echo helo 172.40.201.31
echo mail from:Pratik.Vyas@gmail.com
echo rcpt to:Pratik.Vyas@gmail.com
echo data
echo to:Pratik.Vyas@gmail.com
echo from:Pratik.Vyas@gmail.com
echo "subject: SPARC CQ DB Backup Report : $date :"
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
#echo "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
#echo "Please view attached file"
echo "Content-Type: text/x-log;name="$attached_file""
echo "Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="$attached_file""
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
echo $encoded_log_file
echo $1
sleep 15
echo .
echo ^]
echo quit ) | telnet
echo "status:$?"
echo "Hello done"
}

sendemail
```

Comment: What's with the bass-ackwards date format?

Comment: What does "Mailing Client : Lotus Notes 8.5.2" mean?  As far as I can tell, you have "Mailing Client: ad-hoc shell script"?

Comment: You're not using any mail client, so I'm removing the tag for Lotus-Notes.  If what you're really saying is that the server providing the SMTP service at 172.40.201.35 is Lotus Domino, and you have reason to believe that the problem you are having is caused by the server (i.e., if you use a different SMTP server it works fine, or the server is generating error messages, etc.), then you can re-tag it as Lotus-Domino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rewrite using `/usr/lib/sendmail`.  This is not necessarily the correct location for your system, but you should be able to adapt it.

```
# Function for sending email
sendemail(){
    date=$(date '+%d-%m-%Y')                        # prefer $(...) over `...`
    dbDir=/var/lib/MYSQLBACKUP/$date
    dbname='DBNAME'
    log_file="${dbDir}/${dbname}_${date}.log"
    attached_file="${dbname}_${date}.log"
    echo $log_file
    echo $attached_file
    encoded_log_file=$(openssl base64 < "$log_file")  # notice UUCA fix + quoting
    #echo $encoded_log_file
    # You should configure sendmail to use 172.40.201.31 as your smarthost
    /usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t <<________HERE
to: Pratik.Vyas@gmail.com
from: Pratik.Vyas@gmail.com
subject: SPARC CQ DB Backup Report : $date :
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/x-log; name="$attached_file"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$attached_file"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Ample: notice empty line between headers and body!    # <-- look

$encoded_log_file
$1
________HERE
    echo "status:$?"
    echo "Hello done"
}

sendemail
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a library or command line program (like `mail` or `mailx`) to send mail instead of trying to implement SMTP in a shell script.

Comment: Shell script is not too bad, but piping into `telnet` is particularly prone to go wrong.  It is simply not very suitable for this task.